How to create table witn unique columns in Clickhouse?
I making table "clients" and thing I can't understand.
How to add constraint unique values only for "client_id"?
Here's my query:
CREATE TABLE clients
(
    client_id UInt16 NOT NULL,
    second_name String,
    first_name String,
    patronymic String,
    phone_number String,
    email String,
    discount Float32,
    comment String,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY client_id
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;


The UNIQUE constraint is not supported in ClickHouse. What are you trying to achieve?

I need add constraints for some columns, which must have only unique values.

You can use ReplacingMergeTree and have a table where existing rows with duplicate primary keys get deleted (eventually). I suppose you could make the distinct column the primary key. But ClickHouse does not have a way to enforce unique values on a column.

I think I need read more about ReplacingMergeTree. Check for unique values I make in python script for Airflow.
